# High step up DC-DC converter switch mode power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, boost

I tried to design DC-DC high step up isolated single switch converter and simulate it in Proteus 8 professional, that design have a gain reached to 20 if that possible? and I confused by one thing, I am really new in switch mode power supply especially in isolated ones, but I am notes that the transformers designed as step down anyway if the converter was buck or boost, is that right or not?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1qlzK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

in the above circuit diagram is the proposed topology, is this considered isolated SMPS or not?
I tried to simulate it but I can not get the desired gain as 20.
please, I tried it a few weeks ago but I can not get the desired results.

Comment: Lm, M1, D3, and C3 are connected as a classic Boost Converter. I have no idea what transformer do here. But for sure this circuit is not isolated. primary and secondary are not only share same Ground, but also directly connected to each other via D1.

Comment: One suggestion based on my own work experience: This circuit can be simulated much more comprehensively by LtSpice. If you need this circuit for practical purpose, go to Linear website and take a look at  Power Path control products. most of them can be simulated by LtSpice. I did this and successfully designed and built a high current boost converter.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that circuit? It is unusual and the extra portion at right compared to "normal" (transformer D2 D3 C1) is probably not necessary and it is not at all obvious that this circuit has been "designed".

Lm D1 M1 form a classic boost converter.
Xfmr then attempts to take boost voltage across Lm and "pedestal it" on boost output at D1 cathode, adding N:1 x boost voltage via C1 at D2 Cathode. BUT eg Xfmr primary  becomes part of Lm functionally and must be designed as part of Lm. In fact Lm is not needed with Xfmr present.

Recommendation:  Try removing Xfmr D2 D3 C1 and connect D! cathode to C3 and see how it goes. 20:1 is doable but care needs to be taken with eg stray capacitances which store energy during the flyback  period and reduce voltage rise

After having tried the above, ask for more information if required.